# MS Access OLE Error Attempting to Insert Object

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-access

MS Access 2010 on Windows 7 Pro x64

- Right-click on a cell in a table (Data Type = OLE Object)
- Click on **Insert Object...**
- Select **Create from File**
- Click **Browse** to find .bmp file (844KB)
- Click **OK**

Receive the following error:

> The operation on the OLE object failed.  The OLE server may not be registered. To register the OLE server, reinstall it.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?  I've tried running Access in compatibility mode and making the database a trusted source.  I am not running Norton Antivirus, which some posts say might be the problem. Someone suggested perhaps a graphics program may have been uninstalled incorrectly, but I don't recall removing any software.